# Force Image control to re-download the image

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have an Image control on Page1.xaml that is pointing at a URL: http://www.example.com/blah.jpg

I navigate to Page2.xaml and upload a new image to that url using my WebAPI. I call Frame.GoBack() to navigate back to Page1.xaml.

The old image is still displayed in the Image control. How can I make sure that Image control re-downloads the image even though its at the same URL?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to append a query string to the end of the image. It's a bit of a hack and it can interfere with Save operations but it is effective.

Just to be clear, I set the property with the image url with a value like this:

```
"http://www.example.com/blah.jpg?id=" + Guid.NewGuid()
```

That triggers the RaisePropertyChanged event and the Image control is tricked into thinking the image changed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `BitmapImage.CreateOptions` property to `IgnoreImageCache`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.createoptions):

> The other possible value for CreateOptions is
>   BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache. You should only use
>   BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache in cases where you know that the
>   source image file as retrieved by URI has the potential to change over
>   time. Otherwise, setting CreateOptions to use 
>   BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache causes all newly retrieved image
>   sources to be decoded again, which can negatively impact performance.
>   ...